# Protection from Decompiling/Reverse engineering Android APKs

Tags: java, android, security

Any android developer would know that decompiling your app's APK is somewhat easy and can lead to losing your app.

For example, say I create a custom message ciphering method, encoding and decoding messages on the app side.

How easy is it to lose that kind of private method decompiling?

Also, say that I have some code written in native C++ or C-Make, is that code also easy to decompile?

Comment: "create a custom message ciphering method" you should never do that. Keep the secret in the key, not in the algorithm.

Comment: Use Pro guard rules for the code optimization and for the reverse engineering prevention
https://medium.com/@mittal2810/how-to-safe-app-from-reverse-engineering-d4ca7910d2f